# How to catch Future.failed in Scala?

Tags: scala

Why does this print "Success" instead of "Failure"? How to catch Future.failed?

```
object HelloScala extends App{

      val f = future
      f.map { result => println("Success")
      }.recover { case e =>
        println(e.getMessage)
      }


      def future = Future {
          Future.failed(new Throwable("Failure"))
      }

      Thread.sleep(10000)

}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `def future = Future.failed(new Throwable("Failure"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the type of `f`.

```
val f: Future[Future[_]] = future
```

The inner `Future` fails but the outer `Future` completes with `Success`.